# What's the difference between AS and = in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I just realized that I can write

```
SELECT Descriptive_column_name = Col1234 FROM mytable
```

instead of

```
SELECT Col1234 AS Descriptive_column_name FROM mytable
```

and get seemingly identical results.

Is there any difference between the two? And is there any reason to prefer one or the other?

Comment: Reason to prefer the second one: It works in other DBMS too.

Comment: Functionally, no, but I recommend one use the ANSI/ISO standard SQL syntax as in the second example.

Comment: Purely preference. I personally prefer `AS`, so as not to confuse data and assignment statements. `SELECT {column1} AS {Alias1}, {column2} AS {Alias2} FROM...` vs `SELECT {Variable1} = {column1}, {Variable2} = {Column2} FROM ...`

Comment: The one I hate, hate, hate is `SELECT column alias FROM ...` - I.e. the fact that the `AS` is optional. Which means an accidentally omitted comma between two columns doesn't get reported and you instead get a very odd looking result set.

Comment: Even if there are certain tools / plugins which generate the `Descriptive_column_name = Col1234` I strongly recommend to use the `AS` syntax. And - as Damien already mentioned - even if the AS is optional, do yourself a favour and include it in your code. It eases up things alot. Especially, when you are handling a large number of columns within one statement.